# Runge-Kutta : error while solving a second order differential equation

Tags: python, differential-equations, runge-kutta, nonlinear-equation

I am trying to solve a third order non linear differential equation. I have tried to transform it and I've obtained this problem which is a second order problem:

[image: Main problem to resolve]

I am trying to implement a fourth order Range-Kutta algorithm in order to solve it by writing it like this :

[image: Runge-Kutta problem]

Here is my code for the Range-Kutta algorithm :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

''''X,Y = integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h).
4th-order Runge-Kutta method for solving the initial value problem {y}' = {F(x,{y})}, where {y} = {y[0],y[1],...,y[n-1]}.
x,y = initial conditions
xStop = terminal value of x 
h = increment of x used in integration
F = user-supplied function that returns the 
array F(x,y) = {y'[0],y'[1],...,y'[n-1]}.
'''

def integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h):
    
    def run_kut4(F,x,y,h):
        K0 = h*F(x,y)
        K1 = h*F(x + h/2.0, y + K0/2.0)
        K2 = h*F(x + h/2.0, y + K1/2.0)
        K3 = h*F(x + h, y + K2)
        return (K0 + 2.0*K1 + 2.0*K2 + K3)/6.0
    
    X =[]
    Y =[]
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)
    while x < xStop:
        h = min(h,xStop - x)
        y = y + run_kut4(F,x,y,h)
        x = x + h
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
    return np.array(X),np.array(Y)
```

It works fine for other differential equations.

In this case the function F is defined as :

[image: F function]

And the main code is :

```
def F(x,y):
    F = np.zeros(2)
    F[0] = y[1]
    F[1] = (2*(1-x)/x**3)*y[0]**(-1/2)
    return F

x = 1.0
xStop = 20
y = np.array([0,0])
h = 0.2
X,Y = integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h)
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, I got this error :

```
<ipython-input-8-8216949e6888>:4: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in power
  F[1] = (2*(1-x)/x**3)*y[0]**(-1/2)
<ipython-input-8-8216949e6888>:4: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  F[1] = (2*(1-x)/x**3)*y[0]**(-1/2)
```

It's related to the fact that the initial value of the function is 0 but I don't know how to get rid of it in order to simplify the problem again...

Could someone help me to find an other alternative ?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Is this from your previous `f'''(x)=(1-f)/f^3`, reducing the order by setting `f'(x)=u(f(x))` to get `f''(x)=u'(f(x))*u(f(x))` and `f'''(x)=u''(f(x))*u(f(x))^2+u'(f(x))^2*u(f(x))`? Then the equation becomes `u''(f)=-u'(f)^2/u(f)+(1-f)/f^3/u(f)^2`. Is that on your path or did you try a different substitution?

Comment: It is Carl Runge and Martin Wilhelm Kutta, two very "kaiserlich-deutsche" names.

Comment: Thank you Lutz Lehmann for the reference : yes it is from my previous post. In fact, I used a slightly different substitution by setting : `u(f(x)) = f ' (x)^2` so we have `u '' (f) = 2*f '''(x) * u**(-1/2)`. Due to the fact that the boundary conditions of the previous problem were at infinity : f(inf) = 1, f ' (inf) = 0 and f ' ' (inf) = 0. I think that the new problem seems to be non continuous at 1....

Comment: This parametrization is only valid for strictly monotonous solutions, or restrictions of solutions to such segments. The reference should be the constant solution `f(x)=1` that is not covered by the parametrization. Close to the constant solution you have in the linearization of the difference to it terms `exp(-x)` that are indeed falling towards this constant, but also terms `exp(x/2)*cos(sqrt(3)*x/2)` and the sine variant, which are not monotonous and increasing in amplitude. This alone makes the numerical solution rather unstable, or the problem ill-posed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations : I have tried the substitution that you have proposed earlier setting `f'(x)=u(f(x))`. I got a solution that doesn't seem coherent with what I have expected since I have implemented initial conditions at values different from zero but very close to... It seems to be the best solution version for the moment....

Answer (score 1):

you `y` is `[0,0]` and in `y[0]**(-1/2)` there is division operation with `0` in the denominator which is giving ZeroDivision warning and invalid value encountered in double_scalars is due to expression `y[0]**(-1/2)` changed to `NaN`. however, those are warnings and `F` is returning value `array([ 0., nan])`. you need to replace `y[0]**(-1/2)` as negative powers of zero are undefined or you can use an extremely small value near zero if it suits your need. maybe your equation is not continuous at (1,0).

Comment: thank you for your answer : indeed it was what I've suspected but I'm sorry but I didn't get your advice when you said "check parentheses..." ? could you specify this point please ? thank you again

Comment: parentheses seem to be correct as compared to the pic, I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your precisions : I tried to take a small value near zero and calculations seem to be done until x = 1.2... after that an other error raises : `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  F[1] = (2*(1-x)/x**3)*y[0]**(-1/2)` I don't understand how to manipulate the boundary conditions again in order to simplify this equation if it is not continuous... thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You can test approximate solutions close to the initial point that are powers of `(1-x)` or power series in this difference. In the simplest case you get `y(x)=(1-x)^2` for `x <= 1`. To get solutions for `x>1` you need to take the other sign in the square root. In total this gives a far-field behavior of `x(t)=1+c*exp(-t)`.

Now you can follow two strategies,

- integrate the reduced equation from some initial point `x=1-h` with `y(1-h)=h^2`, `y'(1-h)=-2h`, along with a time integration `dt/dx=y(x)^(-1/2)` where `t(1-h)` is arbitrary, or
- integrate the original equation from some time `t=T` with conditions following the derivatives of `x(t)=1+c*exp(T-t)`, that is, `x(T)=1+c` with arbitrary small `c`, `x'(t)=-c`, `x''(T)=c`.
  In theory they should be the same, practically with fixed-step RK4 in both cases there will be differences.

---

Make a cut across all approaches. Close to the asymptote `x(t)=1` the solution is monotonous and thus time can be expressed in terms of `x-1`. This means that the derivative can (probably) be expressed as power series in `x-1`

```
x'  (t) = c_1 * (x-1) + c_2 * (x-1)^2 + ...
x'' (t) = c_1 * x'(t) + 2c_2 * (x-1)*x' + ...
        = (c_1 + 2c_2*(x-1)+...)*(c_1+c_2*(x-1)+..)*(x-1)
        = c_1^2*(x-1)+3c_1c_2*(x-1)^2 + ...
x'''(t) = (c_1^2+6c_1c_2*(x-1)+...)*(c_1+c_2*(x-1)+..)*(x-1)
        = c_1^3*(x-1) + 7c_1^2c_2*(x-1)^2 + ...

and 

(1-x)/x^3 = -(x-1)*(1+(x-1))^(-3)=-(x-1)+3*(x-1)^2 + ...

so equating coefficients

c_1^3=-1 ==> c_1 = -1
7c_1^2c_2 = 3 ==> c_2 = 3/7

Given x(T) close enough to 1, the other initial values have to be 
x'(T)=-(x(T)-1) + 3/7*(x(T)-1)^2
x''(T)=x(T)-1 -9/7*(x(T)-1)^2
```

Then the far-field approximation due to these first two terms is the solution to

```
x'(t) = -(x-1) + 3/7 * (x-1)^2

Substitute u(t) = (x-1)^(-1) - 3/7

u'(t) = u(t)

(x(t)-1)^(-1) - 3/7 = ((x(T)-1)^(-1) - 3/7) * exp(t-T)

x(t) = 1 + (x(T)-1)*exp(T-t) / ( 1 - 3/7*(x(T)-1)*(1-exp(T-t)) )
```